# Mosquitto responds on Ubuntu on HP Microserver, not on PCDuino

Tags: networking, ethernet

I have a HP Microserver running Ubuntu LTS 18.04, and I use it as a MQTT broker. I port forward port 1883 from my internet router to 172.16.97.2 - the address of my Microserver.

I want to run it on a less intensive device, so I installed a PCDuino, which is also running Ubuntu - Linaro 12.07. It's IP address is 172.16.97.9

The MQTT Broker responds when I do mosquitto_pub from LAN devices on the same segment on both the HP Microserver and the PCduino.

However....

The PCDuino does not respond to external requests after I change the port forwarding address.

I have had trouble trying to change the IP address of eth0 also - I tried the gui "Edit Connections" but it does not have any effect - by that I mean I set eth0 to be a static IP, in Edit Connections, and the device maintains it's dhcp ip address even after a shutdown -r now.

Is there any obvioud places I should look to fix this networking issue?

However, when I change the port

Comment: Looks like a firewall issue on your PCDuino. What does the nmap say, is the port on PCDuino open?

Comment: The MQTT Broker on the PCDuino responds to mosquitto_pub from another computer connected to the same ethernet switch on the same segment, so is it more likely to be a newtwork gateway issue?

Comment: on the other machine, nmap -p 1833 172.16.97.9 returns 1883/tcp open  unknown

Comment: Can you swap the two IP adresses? E.g. PCDuino gets 172.16.97.2? Does the MQTT not require UPNP on PCDuino?